# Why does CroppedBitmap result in an invisible image?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, .net-core

I am attempting to use CroppedBitmap to display a portion of a PNG file on a WPF Image element.

As a test, I have the following code:

```
BitmapImage StandardTilesetImage = new BitmapImage();
StandardTilesetImage.BeginInit();
StandardTilesetImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
StandardTilesetImage.UriSource = new Uri(pngFilePath, UriKind.Relative);
StandardTilesetImage.EndInit();

// TestImage is an Image object defined in XAML
TestImage.Source = StandardTilesetImage;
```

This produces the expected results - the image displays correctly:

[image]

For reference the pngFilePath is a string pointing to the absolute location (`c:/etc/etc/StandardTilesetIcons.png`) which is a 512x512 PNG:

[image]

If I modify the code above to clip a part of the PNG (such as drawing the top-left 64x64 area), the TestImage no longer displays anything.

```
BitmapImage StandardTilesetImage = new BitmapImage();
StandardTilesetImage.BeginInit();
StandardTilesetImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
StandardTilesetImage.UriSource = new Uri(pngFilePath, UriKind.Relative);
StandardTilesetImage.EndInit();

CroppedBitmap croppedBitmap = new CroppedBitmap();
croppedBitmap.SourceRect = new Int32Rect(0,0,64, 64);
croppedBitmap.Source = StandardTilesetImage;
TestImage.Source = croppedBitmap;
```

[image]

I would expect to see a portion of the PNG in my TestImage object. Why is nothing showing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like BitmapImage, CroppedBitmap implements the `ISupportInitialize` interface, which means that when you create an instance by the default constructor, you have to call the `BeginInit()` and `EndInit()` methods before and after setting any of its properties.

Alternatively, use the appropriate constructors with parameters provided by both classes:

```
BitmapImage standardTilesetImage = new BitmapImage(
    new Uri(pngFilePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

CroppedBitmap croppedBitmap = new CroppedBitmap(
    standardTilesetImage, new Int32Rect(0,0,64, 64));

TestImage.Source = croppedBitmap;
```